# Did Axler sleep with with his daughter in the Humbling movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-humbling

In [the humbling](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1568343/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) movie, the hallucinations of the main character (Simon Axler) suggest that he may be guilty for sleeping with his daughter and the hallucinations may be caused by his conscience, similar to [the Machinist](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0361862/?ref_=nv_sr_1).

Has it been made clear in the movies if this is so and if that's the reason Axler kills himself?

Comment: just curious are you implying in the question that hallucinations in the humbling movie are similar to the hallucination sequences in the machinist?

Comment: @JudgeDredd not exactly, as many of the hallucinations in the humbling movie do not follow directly from the crime; but in the end of the movie its claimed that Axler actually had a daughter and that's a good reason for hallucinating the woman that asks him to kill his husband, as well as the sexual relationship with the much younger woman he knew as a 8-10 year girl...